# How can I return rows which match on some columns and fulfil a DateTime comparison between two other columns using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, datetime

I have a table which contains rows for jobs, example below, where 01/01/1980 is used rather than null in the ClosedDate column for jobs which are not finished:

```
JobNumber  JobCategory  CustomerID  CreatedDate  ClosedDate
1          Small        1           01/01/2016   03/01/2016
2          Small        2           03/01/2016   07/01/2016
3          Large        2           06/01/2016   07/01/2016
4          Medium       1           08/01/2016   10/01/2016
5          Small        3           10/01/2016   01/01/1980
6          Medium       3           15/01/2016   01/01/1980
7          Large        2           16/01/2016   17/01/2016
8          Large        2           19/01/2016   20/01/2016
9          Small        1           19/01/2016   01/01/1980
10         Medium       2           19/01/2016   01/01/1980
```

I need to return a list of any jobs where the same customer has had a job of the same category created within 3 days of the previous job being closed.

So, I would want to return:

```
7          Large        2           16/01/2016   17/01/2016
8          Large        2           19/01/2016   20/01/2016
```

because Customer 2 had a Large job closed on 17/01/2016 and another Large job opened on 19/01/2016, which is within 3 days.

In order to do this, I assume I need to compare each record in the table with each subsequent record, looking for a match on JobCategory and comparing CreatedDate with ClosedDate between rows.

Can anyone advise my best option for this using SQL? I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that you should do is get rid of "magic dates" in your system. If the job hasn't been closed yet then the `ClosedDate` is not known. SQL has a value for exactly that - `NULL`. That prevents anyone in the future from having to know the magic date of 1/1/1980 or from that having to be hard-coded throughout your system.

Next, you don't have to compare each row with each one after it. Define what you're looking for and find matches that meet those qualifications. You didn't specify which type of SQL Server you're using (you should tag your question with Oracle or MySQL or SQL Server), so the below query is written for SQL Server. Your version might have different date functions.

```
SELECT
    J1.JobNumber,
    J1.JobCategory,
    J1.CustomerID,
    J1.CreatedDate,
    J1.ClosedDate,
    J2.JobNumber,
    J2.CreatedDate,
    J2.ClosedDate
FROM
    Jobs J1
INNER JOIN Jobs J2 ON
    J2.CustomerID = J1.CustomerID AND
    J2.JobCategory = J1.JobCategory AND
    DATEDIFF(DAY, J1.ClosedDate, J2.CreatedDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 3 AND
    J2.JobNumber <> J1.JobNumber
```

This will return the jobs in a single row instead of two rows. If that's a problem then the query could be altered slightly to do so. This can also be done a little more easily with windowed functions, but again, since you didn't specify your SQL vendor I didn't want to use those.

Since you're using SQL Server, you should be able to use windowed functions like so:

```
;WITH CTE_JobsWithDates AS  -- Probably a poor name for the CTE
(
    SELECT
        JobNumber,
        JobCategory,
        CustomerID,
        CreatedDate,
        ClosedDate,
        LEAD(CreatedDate, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JobCategory, CustomerID ORDER BY CreatedDate) AS NextCreatedDate,
        LAG(ClosedDate, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JobCategory, CustomerID ORDER BY CreatedDate) AS PreviousClosedDate
    FROM
        Jobs
)
SELECT
    JobNumber,
    JobCategory,
    CustomerID,
    CreatedDate,
    ClosedDate
FROM
    CTE_JobsWithDates
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(DAY, ClosedDate, NextCreatedDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 3 OR
    DATEDIFF(DAY, LastClosedDate, CreatedDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 3
```

That was off the cuff, so please test and let me know if anything isn't quite right.

Comment: Thank you Tom, I may have been over complicating it massively! I've been researching loops, counts, with etc, perhaps simpler is better.

I 100% agree about the magic dates, sadly it is something which I have inherrited and cannot change.

Apologies, I should have specified I'm using SQL Server.

How could I use that code but deal with potential multiple occurences? For example, Customer 2 may have had jobs opened within 3 days of another, then another job opened within 3 days of that one. Ideally I would return both rows too.

Very much appreciate your expertise,
Joe

Comment: Try the code and see what happens. You should end up getting two rows back - one for each pair of jobs within 3 days of one another. The two areas where this might give you unexpected results is if a job has the same start and end date along with another matching job. You'll end up with duplicate rows in that case. Also, if three jobs are all squeezed in that 3-day time frame then you'll get each possible combination of pairings which effectively gives you duplicates. I'll add the windowed version that should avoid these issues. Finally, I made a change in the original SQL, so please note that

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
    Job AS a
    JOIN
    Job AS b ON
        a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID AND a.JobCategory = b.JobCategory
WHERE
    a.JobNumber != b.JobNumber
    AND (
        b.CreatedDate - a.ClosedDate BETWEEN 0 AND 3
        OR
        a.CreatedDate - b.ClosedDate BETWEEN 0 AND 3)
```